# Upload image_file using Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create a new Ad Creative for an event ad (**Post-Migration**), using the field `image_file`.

Via the **Graph API Explorer** I send the following post request:

> URL: https://graph.facebook.com//act_xxxx/adcreatives 
>   
>   object_id: xxxxx 
>   
>   body: body here 
>   
>   title: title here 
>   
>   name: name here 
>   
>   image_file: @C:\Art.jpg

I get the following exception response:

> "The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Invalid image file: The image_file field does not specify a POST file name."

Apparently I'm not using the image_file parameter right. How should I use it?

Comment: Would you mind clearing up your exact request in terms of code and readability? If you can specify the exact language show the sample call, it will be easier to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try uploading image only, and than use image hash to upload creative.

Parameters:

```
[
 IMAGE_NAME => '@' + path
]

POST https://graph.facebook.com//act_xxxx/adimages
```

IMAGE_NAME is name with extension - image.jpg, or image.png...

As the response, you will get

```
[
 'images' => [
    [
      'hash' => ...,
      'url' => ....
    ]
  ]
]
```

Than use the image hash you received and create ad creative with that.

If you want to do only one request, do next:

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=...' \
-F 'title=Test title' \
-F 'body=Test body' \
-F 'link_url=http://www.whatever.com' \
-F 'name=test creative' \
-F 'image_file=Art.jpg' \
-F 'Art.jpg=@C:\Art.jpg ' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/act_xxxx/adcreatives'
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround, but I have to send only one http request.  it is said in the facebook ad creative documentation that you can do that with just one call to /adcreatives, specifying only the image_file parameter. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: I have added additional explanation of how you can achieve it in one request. The key is that you should reference parameter with file in file_name.

Basically, file_name=file_that_you_upload.jpg; file_that_you_upload.jpg=@c:/path/to/file.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not use the " image_hash" but rather use a picture as a parameter to specify an image as https://example.com/image.png. Below is an example of the code, object_story_spec is required :

```
{ "link_data": { "picture": "https://prppublicstore.blob.core.windows.net/live-za-images/property/384/35/8570384/images/property-8570384-95103406_sd.jpg", "link": "<<LINK>>", "message": "try it out" }, "page_id": "<<PAGE_ID>>" }
```

A successful response should return an ID of the image as follows:

```
{
"id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```