# Using image_file on facebooks marketing api

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using php sdk (default graph version 2.9)

> ```
>     "facebook/graph-sdk": "5.5.0",
>     "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.2"
> ```

I'm trying to create an ad creative without creating the image first and using it's hash.

```
            $creative = $this->_fb_account->createAdCreative($all_fields, [
            'name'          => 'my first ad creative',
            'title'         => 'my title',
            'body'          => 'my body',
            'image_file'    => '/path/to/my_file.png',
            'object_type'   => AdCreativeObjectTypeValues::DOMAIN,
            'object_url'    => 'http://example.com',
        ]);
```

I get the following error:

> #errorUserTitle: "Invalid image file"
>       #errorUserMessage: "The image_file field does not specify a POST file name."

I can't find anything about this in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative).
Here is a related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592146/upload-image-file-using-ads-api/) which also did not fix the problem.

Comment: have you tried prefixing the file path with an @ symbol?
`'image_file'    => '@/path/to/my_file.png',`

Answer (score 0):

The `image_file` needs to be uploaded in a separate POST request (basically, the PHP `$_FILES` object needs to be populated with the image being uploaded).

One way to achieve this in one request via CURL:

```
curl  \
-F 'image_file=MyImage.png' \
-F 'body=my body' \
-F 'name=my first creative' \
-F 'object_url=http://example.com' \
-F 'title=My Title' \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
-F "MyImage.png=@/path/to/my_file.png" \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_<ACCT_ID>/adcreatives
```