# How to create an Ad Image with a FB sandbox account

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using a sandbox account to test the API calls. Based on the instructions posted here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image I am trying to make a POST call to upload an image so that I can then create an FB Ad. The API comes back with an error

> Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_1234567890' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.

I have looked at this post [Upload image_file using Ads API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592146/upload-image-file-using-ads-api) but neither of the calls worked.

It's worth mentioning that I can create Campaigns and Ad Sets for that sandbox account, I get this permission error only when trying to upload an image so that I can create an AD (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup)

Comment: I opened up a ticket with FB support team and they were able to reproduce the issue and are working on it. I'll post here when I hear back from them.

Comment: Did you ever get a response from Facebook? Were these requests made in the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: @gwely I added an answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer as it appears there are other people who run into this issue (see comment by @gwely).
After a lot of back and forth with FB Support, their response boiled down to

> This probably is a Windows specific question as specifying filename as @path/to/file just works for me. You can try calling the command in the images folder to verify if that works for you."

So I ended up installing CURL on my windows machine and was able to make the call via CURL. The curl command was

```
curl \
-F 'filename=@image_name.jpg' \
-F 'access_token=YOUR_TOKEN' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_115606837999493/adimages"
```

Hope it helps.